#  'cvCreateContourTree' in DLL 'opencv_imgproc231' - deprecated?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, opencv, emgucv

I get this error:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'cvCreateContourTree' in DLL
>   'opencv_imgproc231'.

I am programming in EmguCV 2.3 and have the latest binaries for OpenCV. I checked the DLL exports for 'opencv_imgproc231 and it appears this method is not exported.

Has this method been deprecated? refactored? the documentation seems to state this method is available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function is located at `opencv_legacy231`.

Comment: Thanks, is there an equivalent method we should be using? If it is deprecated, I'd rather not be using it. i.e. how can I compare 2 contours?  PGH? (Note: cvMatchShapes gives me poor results).

Comment: I don't think there's a replacement for this function yet. About your 2nd question, [this thread](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/how-to-compare-two-contours-td2584476.html) has some interesting info.